# Why did Accelerator turn into an angel?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index

In the last episode of season 3 of the anime A certain magical index, Accelerator who is an esper turned into an angel. Why did this happen? Can he do this at will?

Answer (score -1):

Remember the level 6 experiment? Well, he was more than halfway through. So if level 6 is some sort of ascendant tier esper, what's an ascendant tier magic user then? A magic god (you'll learn about those in index new testament)? A saint? An angel?

Well if we say that an ascendant magic user is an angel, then an ascendant esper would be like some sort of science angel right? A science angel seems like an apt description of accelerator's winged power.